# polaris shopify import css issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, polaris

when I try to import styles.css from App.js like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {AppProvider, Page, Card, Button} from '@shopify/polaris';
import '@shopify/polaris/styles.css'; // << issue

import SettingsForm from './SettingsForm';

class App extends React.Component { 
static contextTypes = {
  easdk: PropTypes.object,
};

render() { 
  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <Page title="Settings">
        <SettingsForm />
      </Page>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

I get an error: **Failed to compile**

```
./node_modules/@shopify/polaris/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/@shopify/polaris/styles.css)
Unclosed bracket (3864:37)

  3862 |     background-color:#c4cdd5;
  3863 |     background-color:var(--progress-upper, #c4cdd5);
> 3864 |     background-image:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 0%, transparent 100%, transparent 100% transparent;
       |                                     ^
  3865 |     background-image:linear-gradient(to right, var(--progress-lower, transparent) 0%, var(--progress-lower, transparent) var(--Polaris-RangeSlider-progress, 0%), var(--progress-upper, transparent) var(--Polaris-RangeSlider-progress, 100%), var(--progress-upper, transparent) 100%);
  3866 |     border:none;
```

I verified the css inside  `node_modules/@shopify/polaris/styles.css` is the same as `https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/polaris/2.12.1/polaris.css`

I did a global search for this line `background-image:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 0%, transparent 100%, transparent 100% transparent;` but result came out to 0 
Why am I getting an error here and how can I overcome this please?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue

https://github.com/Shopify/polaris/issues/441

Upgrade to the latest / next version (3.0.0-RC3) and it should be fine.

Comment: from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/polaris/v/3.0.0-rc.3, `npm install @shopify/polaris --save` is the same as ver 2.12

Comment: If you are using yarn then ‘yarn upgrade @shopify/polaris@next’ note that this is a release candidate. If you want to stick with current v2 see workaround in the GitHub issues

Answer (score 0):

Don't import css in node_modules in App.js,if you want to overwrite some settings in node_modules,you should create a css or less file,and import the css in css or less file.And,there are many css property in @shopify/polaris/styles.css,ther is no need to import them all.

Comment: how would I import css or less? what would the syntax look like?

Comment: like this: import ‘./styles.css'

Comment: I think your problem is not the way you import, it's the js-file can‘ analysis the property in " /node_modules/@shopify/polaris/styles.css"

Comment: but that gives an error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'styles.css'`

Comment: emmm,it's  an example,meaning you can create a less or css file like style.css,and add @import "@shopify/polaris/styles.css“ in style.css

Comment: @weber have you been able to resolve the problem?...I'm getting the same issue

Comment: @tee not yet,  but I will definitely share once I do.  Please post if you find a solution as well.